# Gson or Moshi: field in POJO could have 2 types, how to save to any of the fields

Tags: json, kotlin, gson, retrofit, moshi

EDITED:

Here is the json string that I have:

```
json#1
{
    [
        {
            field1 : ""
            field2 : 0
            field3 : "Amount not fixed" or field : 250 // this field can be string or int
        },
        {
            field1 : ""
            field2 : 0
            field3 : "Amount not fixed" or field : 250 // this field can be string or int
        }

    ]
}

json#2
{
    field1 : ""
    field2 : 0
    field3 : "Amount not fixed" or field : 250 // this field can be string or int
}
```

OR it could any json string from server. The point here is there could be 1 or more fields that may have a dynamic value (is this case field3 can be a string or int)

Then I want to deserialize them to any POJO

```
class Temp1 {
    // field1 here
    // field2 here

    @SerializedName("field3")
    val field3Int: Int? = null

    @SerializedName("field3")
    val field3String: String? = null

}
```

It means if the value sent from server is an `Int`, I want to set the value to `field3Int`. If it is a `String`, set to `field3String`.

There could be other POJO that will have these kind of fields that may have dynamic value.

Thanks to Serj to his answer but I still cant make it work on the TypeAdapter class after I edited the question to show my real situation.

Btw. I use this with Retrofit2 like this:

```
val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
                    .add(MultitypeJsonAdapterAdapter())
                    .build()
            return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)

                    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .build()
```

Comment: do `field1` and `field2` have fixed types or they are also dynamic?

Comment: also in your example, `json#1` is not a valid JSON.

Comment: @SerjLotutovici any field could be dynamic. in this pojo, its only field3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I got what I want to achieve. And no need to use any adapter.
If a field can have any dynamic type, you need to declare it as Any in your POJO. Then if you want to use its actual value, you just need to check its type and cast it. So the POJO should like this:

```
class Temp1 {
    // field1 here
    // field2 here

    @SerializedName("field3")
    val field3: Any? = null

    fun getField3Str() : String {
        return when (field3) {
            is String -> field3 as String
            is Int -> {
                "%d".format(field3 as Int)
            }
            is Double -> {
                "%d".format(field3.toInt())
            }
            else -> ""
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

With `Moshi` you can leverage form the polymorphic deserialization feature. Just write a custom adapter that will use `JsonReader#readJsonValue()`. See code below:

```
data class Multitype constructor(val fieldInt: Int?, val fieldString: String?) {
  constructor(fieldInt: Int) : this(fieldInt, null)
  constructor(fieldString: String) : this(null, fieldString)
}

class MultitypeJsonAdapterAdapter {
   @FromJson fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): Multitype {
      val jsonValue = reader.readJsonValue() as Map<String, Any?>
      val field = jsonValue["field"]
      return when (field) {
        is String -> Multitype(field)
        is Double -> Multitype(field.toInt()) // readJsonValue parses numbers as Double
        else -> throw JsonDataException("Expected a field of type Int or String")
      }
   }

   @ToJson fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: Multitype?) {
     TODO("not implemented")
   }

}

class MultitypeJsonAdapterAdapterTest {
  @Test fun check() {
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
      .add(MultitypeJsonAdapterAdapter())
      .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
      .build()

    val adapter = moshi.adapter(Multitype::class.java)

    val fromJson1 = adapter.fromJson("""{ "field": 42 }""")
    assertThat(fromJson1).isEqualTo(Multitype(42))

    val fromJson2 = adapter.fromJson("""{ "field": "test" }""")
    assertThat(fromJson2).isEqualTo(Multitype("test"))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Serj for the help. Btw, I edited the question and I struggling on the @FromJson fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader) part. Need help =/